# Bitcoinjs browser compile creating empty file

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, bitcoin

I'm attempting to do a build of Bitcoinjs for browser testing folloing the instructions on the [BitcoinJS page](http://bitcoinjs.org/) (included below).

```
$ npm install -g bitcoinjs-lib

$ npm -g install bitcoinjs-lib browserify uglify-js
$ browserify -r bitcoinjs-lib -s Bitcoin | uglifyjs > bitcoinjs.min.js
```

When I run this is does generate a file called bitcoinjs.min.js but it is empty. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you save the output from browserify and don't pipe to uglify?

Comment: @JMM Same, blank file.

Comment: hey Ben, did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score -1):

what does your index.js look like?

try the following: Create index.js with the following content in the same folder:

```
var bitcoin = {
  base58: require('bs58'),
  bitcoin: require('bitcoinjs-lib'),
  ecurve: require('ecurve'),
  BigInteger: require('bigi'),
  Buffer: require('buffer'),
  elliptic: require('elliptic'),
  bs58check: require('bs58check'),
}
module.exports = bitcoin;
```

Then run:

```
browserify index.js -s bitcoin | uglifyjs > bitcoinjs.min.js
```